# the 'A' link doesn't work on the iframe only from iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, iframe, safari

The link of 'A' tag doesn't work correctly. Does anyone explain this behavior?

Here is the NG sample -> http://hovertest.dyndns.org/ng/main.html

Visit from iPhone(or iPad) safari and scroll the iframe and click 'NIGHT' link at the bottom of the iframe page.
It will not go to 'night.html'. (You may get the top of the same page. This is wrong behavior.)

But, It will work correctly after removing the 'background' of 'a:hover' from CSS.

I can't understand at all.

Here is the good sample -> http://hovertest.dyndns.org/ok/main.html

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NG LINK </title>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Main
<div style="height: 50%; overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <iframe src="./content.html" />
</div>
```

content.html

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="hover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>

<a href="./morning.html">MORNING</a>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<a href="./night.html">NIGHT</a>
</body>
</html>
```

hover.css

```
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  background: red;
}
```

At first, I tried to remove 'a:hover' of CSS from 'main.html' by jQuery. 
But, I couldn't get rid of this problem.

I can't change 'content.html' and 'hover.css' for other reasons.

Do you have any ideas for avoiding this issue? or explain this behavior?

Thanks,
Y.Sato

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The links are broken. I would suggest to make new demos on http://jsbin.com.